# Rails - return an array of months for a select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, date, select

I'm in an app that is on Rails 2.3.8, and need to return an array of month names and numbers to be plugged into an options_for_select statement.  What I've got so far is kind of working, but not really.  The reason I'm doing things this way is because the select statement needs a prompt, which you can't give options_for_select by default in 2.3.8 (at least to my knowledge).

Here is what I have so far:

```
@months = [['-', '']]
(1..12).each {|m| @months << [[Date::MONTHNAMES[m], m]]}
```

So what I'm looking to get returned are options like this:

```
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
```

However, instead I get:

```
<option value="January1">January1</option>
<option value="February2">February2</option>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this!

```
@months = [['-', '']]
(1..12).each {|m| @months << [Date::MONTHNAMES[m], m]}
```

Comment: Yep, too many brackets. You can compress it even more using `map`, and pass it to `options_for_select`: `options_for_select((1..12).map {|m| [Date::MONTHNAMES[m], m]})`.

Comment: @Douglas: I would upvote your answer if you had left it as one :)

Comment: This is awesome! And brilliant update by @DouglasFShearer! This is exactly one of the reasons I'm moving to Ruby from Python, lol

Comment: In case anyone is looking for how to do this while supporting internationalization:  `(1..12).map {|m| I18n.l(DateTime.parse(Date::MONTHNAMES[m]), format: "%B")}`

Answer (score 19):

```
Date::MONTHNAMES.each_with_index.collect{|m, i| [m, i]}
=> [[nil, 0], 
    ["January", 1], 
    ["February", 2], 
    ["March", 3], 
    ["April", 4], 
    ["May", 5], 
    ["June", 6], 
    ["July", 7], 
    ["August", 8], 
    ["September", 9], 
    ["October", 10], 
    ["November", 11], 
    ["December", 12]]
```

#### Abbreviated selection with default option

```
Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES.compact.each_with_index.collect{|m, i| [m, i+1]}
                     .insert(0, ['Please Select', nil])
=> [["Please Select", nil], 
    ["Jan", 1], 
    ["Feb", 2], 
    ["Mar", 3], 
    ["Apr", 4], 
    ["May", 5], 
    ["Jun", 6], 
    ["Jul", 7], 
    ["Aug", 8], 
    ["Sep", 9], 
    ["Oct", 10], 
    ["Nov", 11], 
    ["Dec", 12]]
```

Comment: Extremely minor note: `to_a` does the same thing as your first map.

Answer (score 11):

You can use rails helper select_month, like:

```
select_month(Date.today)
```

Comment: How do you use that inside of a form-helper, though?

Answer (score 2):

**This is my solution for you**, in case you work with **I18n-based projects**, that requires multilingual features:

```
def month_array
  # Gets the first day of the year
  date = Date.today.beginning_of_year
  # Initialize the months array
  months = {}

  # Iterate through the 12 months of the year to get it's collect
  12.times do |i| # from 0 to 11
    # Get month name from current month number in a selected language (locale parameter)
    month_name = I18n.l(date + i.months, format: '%B', locale: :en).capitalize
    months[month_name] = i + 1
  end
  return months
end

# => {"January"=>1, "February"=>2, "March"=>3, "April"=>4, "May"=>5, "June"=>6, "July"=>7, "August"=>8, "September"=>9, "October"=>10, "November"=>11, "December"=>12}
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Here's a *sexy* way to get the months only if that's all you want:

```
Date::MONTHNAMES.slice(1..-1).map(&:to_sym)
```

Answer (score 1):

Working for ROR 4

```
select_month(0 , prompt: 'Choose month')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be translated to the selected language.

```
t("date.month_names")
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this nifty way to shift off the first `nil` but return a new collection of months. You cannot use shift on it since that would try to modify the frozen variable.

```
Date::MONTHNAMES.drop(1)
```

Comment: You can use Date::MONTHNAMES.compact if you want to remove nil values

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<% (1..12).each do |month|%>
  <%= link_to t('date.month_names')[month], '#' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# alternative 1 
Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.zip(1.upto(12)).to_h

# alternative 2
Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.zip([*1..12]).to_h
```

Outputs:

> {"January"=>0, "February"=>1, "March"=>2, "April"=>3, "May"=>4,
>   "June"=>5, "July"=>6, "August"=>7, "September"=>8, "October"=>9,
>   "November"=>10, "December"=>11}

Example:

```
# using simple_form
f.input :month, collection:  Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.zip(1.upto(12)).to_h
```