# Rails how to create an array of months for a select tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My question is similar to [Rails - return an array of months for a select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567394/rails-return-an-array-of-months-for-a-select-tag).

But I want an array like this:

```
[
  ["September", 9], 
  ["August", 8],
  ["July", 7], 
  ["June", 6],
  ["May", 5], 
  ["April", 4],
  ["March", 3],
  ["February", 2],
  ["January", 1],
  ["December", 0]
  ["November", -1], 
  ["October", -2]
]
```

And if the current month were October, it would be:

```
[
  ["October", 10]
  ["September", 9], 
  ["August", 8],
  ["July", 7], 
  ["June", 6],
  ["May", 5], 
  ["April", 4],
  ["March", 3],
  ["February", 2],
  ["January", 1],
  ["December", 0]
  ["November", -1]
]
```

Comment: def months 
   months = [['-', '']]
   (1..12).each {|month| months << [Date::MONTHNAMES[month], motnh]}
end

and add the method to your select_tag options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
require 'date'
Date::MONTHNAMES[1..12].reverse.rotate(12-Time.now.month).each_with_index.collect{|m, i| [m, Time.now.month-i]}
```

Edit:

As you mentioned in a comment you wanted to display the year, you need a different approach to “go back in time”.  As you are using rails, you can use activerecord’s date functions to do that:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/date/calculations'
t = Time.now
(0..11).collect { |i| current = t.advance(months:-i); ["#{Date::MONTHNAMES[current.month]} #{current.year}", t.month-i ] }
```

Comment: Super. How to add the year behind the month name?

Comment: If you want the year, you’ll need a different approach I think, as you need to figure out the year change at December of the previous year.

Comment: I was thinking if it is possible to just add 2011 to all the negativ and zero values. I think it would be the easiest solutiomn.

Comment: Didn't know about [Array#rotate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-rotate), great use of it!

Comment: @Railsbeginner I have added an alternative way that goes backwards to display the month along with the year.

Comment: How do I set the values to be a date like the first day of the month?

Comment: Aha: current.beginning_of_month.strftime("%F")

Comment: It will return the exact month with number. Date::MONTHNAMES[1..12].reverse.rotate(12-Time.now.month).each_with_index.collect{|m, i| [m, Time.now.month-i > 0 ? Time.now.month-i : Time.now.month-i+12]}